# PDP schemes parameter generation

Tags: rsa

For the PDP scheme, I need to generate the following parameter:
g is a generator of Q (Q is the set of quadratic residues modulo N (N = pq is the RSA modulus)
What algorithm can be used to generate this parameter most effectively?

Comment: All but answered [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/167478/35016).

Comment: To summarize the answer: pick $p, q$ to be distinct safe primes ($(p-1)/2, (q-1)/2$ are also prime), then pick an arbitrary $r$ and set $g = r^2 \pmod{pq}$; as long as $\gcd(pq, g-1) = 1$, then $g$ will generate the entire group.  If you don't want to bother messing with $r$, you can just note that $g=4$ will work...